# Running Delayed_Job on Unicorn with 2 web dynos

Tags: heroku, delayed-job

I have 2 web dynos active on Heroku.

I'm running Unicorn and Cedar-14.

```
#unicorn.rb 

worker_processes 3
timeout 30

#Procfile.rb

web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

How can I run delayed_job using Unicorn processes? I want 2 Dynos to keep the server online but don't want to pay for an additional "worker" dyno to process some lengthy database actions.

I've seen examples for using resque but nothing concrete for Unicorn + DelayedJob.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into the same thing lately and while I have yet to implement anything, the consensus is that the best way to accomplish this is to spin up work dynos when you need then and spin them down when you're finished.

There are a few gems that do this but from what I've seen, they all have drawbacks. I've also read that there are some services that will charge a small monthly fee to handle this which eliminated the issues the various gems had.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That seems to be the consensus. Unfortunately the monthly fees from the services can cost as much as a dyno! I need background processes sporadically (unpredictably, depending on user input). So for now I've just left it using async jobs